# Why does apache not define where to log by default?

Tags: logs, apache-httpd, configuration

When searching the occurrence of the chain `/var/log` in default configuration files of apache this cannot be found anywhere.

But log files are defined as such

```
# part of httpd.conf
ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

I cannot understand how does apache decide where to placed its error log file.

Why does not apache define exactly where the log files will be sent?  Or, if you prefer, where is defined the root directory for log files in apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use absolute path, `apache` assume that it's relative path to `ServerRoot` directive.

According to `apache` doc:

> The ErrorLog directive sets the name of the file to which the server
>   will log any errors it encounters. If the file-path is not absolute
>   then it is assumed to be relative to the ServerRoot.

In almost `apache` version, `ServerRoot` default set to `/usr/local/apache`.